# Simplified expression for $\left| \dfrac{1}{1+z^{9}}\right| \leq \dfrac{C}{|z^9|}$ for $|z| > 1$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

It is clear that the poles lies on the unit circle, wherefore I think such expression is possible since the denominator will never be zero. In the best of cases, I would assert $|z^9| \leq |1 + z^9|$ and so forth,

$$\left|\dfrac{1}{1+z^9} \right| \leq \left|\dfrac{1}{z^9}\right|$$ for $|z|>1$, however I am not sure if this is right. However, I think it is possible to instead have,
$$\left|\dfrac{1}{1+z^9} \right| \leq C\left|\dfrac{1}{z^9}\right|$$ for $|z|>1$ and $C< \infty$.

Thanks in advance for any hints on how I can take it from here.

Comment: What is your question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such constant $C$. If you let $z $ tend to a $9-$th root of $-1$ through values outside the unit disk you will immediately get a contradiction to the inequality.  More specifically, put $z=-1-\frac  1n$ in the  inequality and let $n \to \infty$ to get a  contradiction.

Comment: What happens if one weaken the equality to e.g. $|z|\geq2$, then there would not be such contradiction right?

Comment: @WorseThanEuler In that case $C=\frac {2^{9}} {2^{9}-1}$ works.

Answer (score 0):

The exponent $9$ is immaterial and you are essentially asking for an upper bound on

$$\left|\frac z{z+1}\right|$$ for $|z|>1$. Even in the reals, this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

As already explained in the other answers there is no such $C$ as long as you wish $|z|>\color{blue}{1}$.

But if you can relax the lower bound to $|z|^9 >\color{blue}{1+\epsilon}$ for a fixed $\epsilon >0$, you can find a corresponding $C_{\epsilon}$ using the reverse triangle inequality:

$$\frac 1{|z^9+1|}= \frac 1{|z|^9\left|1+\frac 1{z^9}\right|}$$$$\leq \frac 1{|z|^9\left|1-\frac 1{|z|^9}\right|}\stackrel{|z|^9>1+\epsilon}{<}\underbrace{\frac{\epsilon}{1+\epsilon}}_{=C_{\epsilon}}\cdot \frac 1{|z|^9}$$